# Printing a 'newline' after printing 1 through N consecutive numbers recursively

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, printing

I wrote the following recursive function to print 1 through N:

```
print('-'*20)
def print_nums(N):
    count = N
    assert N >= 0

    if N <= 1: 
        print(N, end='')
    else:
        print_nums(N-1)
        print(' ',N, end='')
        
    # print('\n')

print_nums(5)
```

and the output looks like the following:

[image]

I want the terminal prompt to be printed from the next line of the program output, i.e., I want to print a newline after the function has finished printing 1 through N consecutive numbers. I don't want to print a new line after calling the function; that is, I want the `print_nums(N)` function to be complete and independent so that anyone calling the function won't have to remember to print a new line every time they call the function.

Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Answer (score 0):

If you line to add extra line gap after printing the row you can achieve thorugh this

```
print('-'*20)
def print_nums(N, line_gap=True):
    count = N
    assert N >= 0

    end = "\n" if line_gap else ""

    if N <= 1:
        print(N, end=end)
    else:
        print_nums(N-1, line_gap=False)
        print(' ',N, end=end)

    # print('\n')

print_nums(5)
```

Comment: Is it impossible without the line_gap parameter? If so, then could it be done in any other programming language?